# Flutter Error IMAGE: Unable to load asset

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to get flutter pub get, tried several ways to add the image

My pubspec.yaml

```
flutter:
uses-material-design: true
assets:  
- assets/images/
```

Especific code in main.dart

```
     decoration: new BoxDecoration(        
                image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/images/thermo.png'),
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
                color: Color.fromRGBO(78, 144, 30, 1),                         
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: const Radius.circular(30.0),
                topRight: const Radius.circular(30.0),
                bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(30.0),
                bottomRight: const Radius.circular(30.0),
              )        
            ),
```

Debug Console

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: assets/images/thermo.png

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load
package:flutter/…/services/asset_bundle.dart:225
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:668
#2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:651
```

The hierarchy of folders:

[image: The hierarchy of folders]

Comment: YAML is whitespace sensitive. Check your indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indentations(spaces) are highly important in pubspec.yaml file. Your issue is related to this. You can fix it like this:

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:  
    - assets/images/
```

Comment: Thank you! Work now